# Running one grails instance with two ports

Tags: grails

I need your advice on grail network connectivity.

I have port 80 for sending and receiving grails views. I have iOS devices needing to send data (json)to the same grails instance, preferably on a different port.

Can this be done with Grails?

Newb in grails

Comment: Just curious: why on a different port? What's the difference?

Comment: I want the Json port to be a sort of heartbeat and receive ios data.

Comment: Why can the heartbeat not be on the main port? What do you gain by it being separate?

Comment: Hmm yes you are probably right

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do that. The only thing is that you need your application to listen to another port. There is a library for that : http://camel.apache.org/

There is a grails plugin also available for this library: http://grails.org/plugin/routing

You would be doing something like below. Install the above grails plugin.

- Define a camel route

  ```
  from("http://localhost:8090").to("bean:myService?method=myMethod")
  ```

Once done your application will start listening to 8090 port and anything which comes to this port will be directed to myMethod of myService class.

You may also have to install or add http://camel.apache.org/http.html component to the buildConfig.

The route will start as soon as your application is up and you could check it with below command.

```
netstat -an | grep "8090"
```

Please add comment if you face difficulties in setting it up.

Comment: Thanks @Lalit! I'll try it out when i get home later

Comment: I wouldn't encourage this solution. Even though it'll get you (maybe) the result you're looking for, it's subverting the Grails flow, which is likely something you do not want.

Comment: Hmm @DanielWoods what does subverting grails flow mean? I just starting out and would appreciate any tips you can share

Comment: As in, this will be a completely new injection point into the application -- will not flow through filters that retain the Grails context.

Comment: @DanielWoods You might be right but there are times we need a separate port for processing. We have used this approach for our HL7 processing which is now in production and works perfectly. We were also filtering out things which got into our port using camel HL7 headers. So, only those messages will make into our systems which is necessary. I don't understand why would you not encourage using routing plugin as it already has 8 five star votes which means there are a lot of people using it.

Comment: It's nothing against the plugin, it is against the technique... And w/r/t filters -- that's not what I'm talking about. Grails has Servlet Filters that ensure the Grails context during requests (not sessions). Without these in place, things won't work the way you expect.